# How to resolve this computability paradox?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Let's define two Turing machines, $T_1$ and $T_2$, as follows: Given a number $n$ as input, let $T_1$ be a Turing machine that enumerates over all pairs $(p,s)$ where $p$ is the code of some Turing machine and $s$ is a number of computational steps, simulates $p$ for $s$ steps, outputs the result if it is the $nth$ result computed in this way. (So for input "7" $T_1$ will output the result of simulating $p$ in the 7th $(p,s)$ pair for $s$ steps).

Let $T_2$ be a program that takes $T_1$'s input for some $n$, and outputs that input with another '1' bit appended at the end. As far as I can see there is no problem in the definition of $T_2$, since it merely runs $T_1$ on a given input and then appends a bit at the end.

The paradox is this: Based on $T_1$ and $T_2$'s code, their output should never be the same for some $n$. However, since both machines always halt there necessarily exists an $n$ for which $T_1$ simulates $T_2$ on input $n$ for enough computational steps to know $T_2$'s output for input $n$. In this case it seems like both programs should output the same result - a contradiction.

How does one resolve this?

Comment: As defined, T2 will always take at least 1 step more than T1 before it actually halts and outputs anything.

Comment: When $T_1$ simulates $T_p$, which input does it give $T_p$? If all it ever computes is $p(0)$, then there is no contradiction with $T_2$ being able to output a large number when its input $n$ is _not_ $0$.

Comment: @BrianO I think this issue can be taken care of by providing a less or more efficient version of $T_1$ to $T_2$ (that still has the same input); this is always possible by making $T_1$ slower

Comment: @HenningMakholm If I understand your q -- it simply simulates the program $p$ where $p$ is a binary string representation for it. The binary representation might include an input for the program $T_p$. The contradiction is that $T_2(n) = T_1(n) + 1$, but there is presumably an $n$ such that $T_1(n) = T_2(n)$.

Comment: A question re a detail: T1 on $n=⟨p,s⟩$ runs the $p^{th}$ TM for $s$ steps on what input? Ah I see @HenningMakholm asks the same. I had asked earlier but stupidly deleted it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes that should work — there are arbitrarily slower version of $T_1$.

Comment: @Michael: So what you're saying is that your $T_1$ is actually enumerating _triples_ $(p,d,s)$ and simulating $T_p$ on input $d$ for at most $s$ steps? That is an important difference, betcause $T_2$ corresponds to a definite $p$, but _not_ to a definite $d$. When you know $T_2$ you can identify a particular $p$ to look at -- but you can't know which $d$ to look at before you have chosen $n$, and vice versa -- so nobody says there will be any $d$ and $n$ that correspond to each other!

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, it does seem to be the case, but given that we can choose any enumeration for $n$  there doesn't seem to be a reason to think we can't select some arbtiary enumeration where there are infinitely many pairs for which $d=n$

Comment: @Michael: As far as I can see, your construction amounts to _exactly_ a diagonalization argument that such an enumeration will not exist. Note that for every change to your enumeration, you're changing what $T_1$ is, and therefore also what $T_2$ and its $p$ is -- so the triples that correspond to $T_2$ are now a different part of the triple space.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah, naturally the two conclusions both falsify each other, so one of the assumptions I'm making has to be false; the problem is that I don't exactly see that *why* this enumeration would not exist, or why the paradox can't be modified a little to enable it. Basically, I don't have any intuition for why this paradox is false.

Comment: @Michael: I don't know what to say then. You yourself have provided a _proof_ that an enumeration like you describe can't exist (and no particular reason to assume it _would_ exist) -- so I'm quite confused that you can keep saying that you "don't exactly see _why_" the thing you have proved is true.